# ZSSRichTextEditor style buttons are not working

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

Regarding ZSSRichTextEditor 0.5.2.1 (CocoaPods implementation)

Using the [ZSSRichTextEditor](https://github.com/nnhubbard/ZSSRichTextEditor), I have buttons for Bold, Italic, Strikethrough, Underline, Ordered & Unordered Lists, and Indent & Outdent. The Bold, Italic, Strikethrough, and Underline buttons apply their style to my text, however the remaining buttons do nothing. The functional buttons always display a message in the console output, but the non-functional buttons do not. I have set breakpoints inside the methods of the non-functional buttons, and those breakpoints never hit.

Even for the buttons that are functional, in the demo app they each display in Black while active (or Blue if inactive), but the color does not change in my implementation.

My subclass of ZSSRichTextEditor works in the demo app, but not in my project:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.enabledToolbarItems = @[ZSSRichTextEditorToolbarBold, ZSSRichTextEditorToolbarItalic, ZSSRichTextEditorToolbarUnderline, ZSSRichTextEditorToolbarStrikeThrough, ZSSRichTextEditorToolbarUnorderedList, ZSSRichTextEditorToolbarOrderedList, ZSSRichTextEditorToolbarIndent, ZSSRichTextEditorToolbarOutdent, ZSSRichTextEditorToolbarViewSource];
    self.placeholder = @"Tap here to Edit";
}
```

Placeholder text is non-functional in both the demo and my app.

Anyone have any luck with this library, or these issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There appears to be a bug in the ZSSRichTextEditor library, causing the farm of the toolbar to sometimes be less wide than it needs to be. To patch this, in ZSSRichTextEditor.m I replaced:

```
self.toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
self.toolbar.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
```

With:

```
self.toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:self.toolBarScroll.frame];
```

This works since the toolbar's horizontal scrollview (self.toolBarScroll) is already being set to the width of the view you are using, now allowing the toolbar to fill the space of that scrollview.